# iOS6: CBPeripheral is being dealloc'ed while connecting

Tags: objective-c, ios6, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I'm trying to connect to a bluetooth BTLE device. I have no problem discovering the peripheral.

However, when I attempt to connect to the peripheral, I received the following warning.

> 2013-04-05 22:10:36.110 CoreBluetooth[WARNING]  7DA9E322-D710-081B-4A9D-526DE546B13C, Name = "Find My Car Smarter", IsConnected = NO> is being dealloc'ed while connecting

Furthermore, neither of the relevant delegate methods are called:

```
didConnectPeripheral:
didFailToConnectPeripheral:
```

I've been struggling with this for hours...
Please help.

Answer (score 38):

Short answer: You need to retain the peripheral.

Long explanation: Core Bluetooth does not know whether you are interested in this peripheral when it is discovered. Connecting to it is not enough, you need to retain it.

Add a property to the class where you are doing all that:

```
@property (strong) CBPeripheral     *connectingPeripheral;
```

And then assign the peripheral to this property when the device is discovered, before you return from `didDiscoverPeripheral`:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
  DDLogVerbose(@"Discovered peripheral: %@ advertisement %@ RSSI: %@", [peripheral description], [advertisementData description], [RSSI description]);

  [central connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
  self.connectingPeripheral = peripheral;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! This has been driving me crazy... Much thanks!

Comment: Please approve the answer (the green tick next to it). It helps people know that this answer works and me to get some more points and badges ;)

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I'm keeping the reference in an array but when I try to connect I get this same error.

@property NSMutableArray *heartRateMonitors;
[self setHeartRateMonitors:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
[[self heartRateMonitors] addObject:peripheral]; 

If I store it in an individual variable like your example the problem goes away.  Any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: The array should retain the objects it contains but maybe you are releasing the array too early? You should add a debug message in the dealloc method of your object to make sure the object itself is not released (which would release the heartRateMonitors property).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've been stuck on it for a while